# googletrans not fully translating from English to Italian

Tags: python, translation, google-translate, google-translation-api, google-translator-toolkit

I have just installed the library `googletrans` but when i try to translate a simple sentence from English to Italian, it does not work properly. Here is the code:

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

translation = translator.translate('The quick brown fox', src='en', dest='it')
print(translation.origin, ' -> ', translation.text)
```

The output is the following: `The quick brown fox  ->  Il quick brown fox` As you can see the translated part is still in English except the article (`The -> Il`). How is this possible? How can i make it work correclty?

Note: by using the [google translate website](https://translate.google.it/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=it&text=The%20quick%20brown%20fox) i am able to obtain the right translation: `La rapida volpe marrone`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question. My best guess is there exists some kind of bug in the *Translator*.

Meanwhile, I can suggest you using [translate](https://pypi.org/project/translate/).

`pip install translate`

```py
from translate import Translator
translator = Translator(to_lang='it')
translation = translator.translate('The quick brown fox')
print(translation)
```

The output will be exactly as you wish:
`La rapida volpe marrone`